# Android: Permission denied when creating a new file in external storage

Tags: android, android-file

I am trying to write a file to the external storage location on Android. Here is my code :

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
     saveState= true;
     File pPath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

     if(!pPath.exists()) {
          boolean bReturn= pPath.mkdirs();
          Log.d(TAG, "mkdirs returned: " + bReturn);
     }
     try {
          File pFile= new File(pPath, "output.pcm");
          pFile.createNewFile();
          outputLocation= pFile.getAbsolutePath().toString();
     } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Could not create file: " + e.toString());
          saveState= false;
     }
} // end if we can read/write to the external storage
```

The call to createNewFile() returns  "Could not create file: java.io.IOException: Permission denied"

I have the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in my manifest file. There seems to be a ton of questions about this problem, and this solved most of them, but I am still having this issue. Here is part of the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="company.example.sample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></permission>
    <permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"></permission>
    <permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></permission>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace your `<permission>` elements with `<uses-permission>` elements:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

`<permission>` defines a new permission; `<uses-permission>` indicates you want to hold a permission.

Comment: Wow, that was it. Isn't my face red!

Comment: @rotaludom: Well, actually, I can't tell what color your face is right now. Could you turn a bit to your left? No, no, your other left. Ah, yes, your face is a bit red. It was just tough to tell until you turned to face the hidden webcam. Glad we cleared that up! :-)