# Creation file does not work in android

Tags: android, file, android-activity, android-manifest, creation

I using the following code:

```
 String outputFile = "/mnt/sdcard/mydir/myApp.apk"
 File f = new File(outputFile);

 if(!f.exists())
       f.createNewFile();

 // *** other code ***
```

But when the application reaches the line

```
 f.createNewFile();
```

nothing appens. The other code linees are not executed and no error occurs.

The activity from where I executed this code is configured in manfiest in this way:

```
 <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
        android:name=".ACT_ImpostazioniAvanzate"  android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This activity is not the main activity, and in the manifest I obtain the following Waring:

```
 "Exported activity does not require permission"
```

What does this mean? May be related to my creation file problem?

Comment: See there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931662/android-permission-denied-when-creating-a-new-file-in-external-storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your warning is unrelated to your issue with creating files.

You don't have the proper permission set to write to the external storage on the device.

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your manifest above the `<activity` tag

If you want more info about the warning in the manifest take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333988/warning-exported-activity-does-not-require-permission)

Comment: With high reputation, You should flag duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful /mnt/sdcard/ may not work on all the devices, you should use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and check also the permission in the manifest as said in the comments

Comment: I know. The outputfile string is generated in this way:

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/mydir/Host4.apk";

But this retrievs the /mnt/sdcard/... directory